# I can get an object, but not its properties in JS

Tags: javascript, class, object, filter

I have a ul where the lis are populated with content from an array of `Category`. I need to access another property for the corresponding object based on the li that was clicked though (if I could get its index in the ul that would also be enough, but I haven't found a way to do it).

If I run:

```
var thisCategoryObject = filteredCategories.filter(value => value.name == selectedCategory)[0];
console.log(thisCategoryObject);
```

[image]

However this, returns an error.

```
var thisCategoryObject = filteredCategories.filter(value => value.name == selectedCategory)[0];
console.log(thisCategoryObject.sizeType);
```

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'thisCategoryObject.sizeType')

This is probably a silly question, but does anyone know what I'm missing?
I can't access other properties of this object either.

Additional context below:

```
class Category {
constructor(name, parent, sizeType) {
    this.name = name;
    this.parent = parent;
    this.sizeType = sizeType;
}
}


var categories = [

// Contains a long list of category objects, some of which are sub-categories of others.
new Category("Electronics", null, null),
..
new Category("Video Gaming Merchandise", "Gaming", null),
..
new Category("Jeans", "Women", "womenTrousers"),
]

// Then the function that renders the appropriate categories, filters the children and displays them once a parent is selected. What I need is to get the .sizeType of the selected category.

var ul = document.getElementById("categories");
var selectedCategory;
var isFashionCategory;
var filteredCategories = [];


function renderCategories(categoryArray){
    for (i in categoryArray) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");

        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(categoryArray[i].name));

        li.onclick = function () {
            selectedCategory = this.textContent;
            localStorage.setItem('selectedCategory', selectedCategory);

            // This will find the Category object with the name of the selectedCategory in the filteredCategories array
            var thisCategoryObject = filteredCategories.filter(value => value.name == selectedCategory)[0];
            console.log(thisCategoryObject.sizeType);

            this.parentElement.innerHTML = '';
            filteredCategories = categories.filter(value => value.parent == selectedCategory)

            if (filteredCategories.length != 0) {
                renderCategories(filteredCategories);
            } else {
                // window.location.href = '../index.html';
            }
        };

        ul.appendChild(li);
    }        

}


var startCategories = categories.filter(value => value.parent == null)
renderCategories(startCategories);
```

Comment: the working code and the erroring one are the same

Comment: My mistake @Taki, the first one just logs thisCategoryObject

Comment: Without more context it's hard to say what's wrong; the error means that `thisCategoryObject` is `undefined`, which would in turn mean that the `.filter()` returned an empty array.

Comment: @CristianMoisei could you please add some code before the variable allocation to show how you populate your object?

Comment: Thanks @Pointy, I've shared more details. What's strange to me is that I can log the object, just not its properties. Maybe there's something I don't understand about how JS works.

Comment: Sure @Nicolas Guérinet, I've added more details

Comment: It may be due to the fact that .filter works on 'Arrays' but your filtering on the first object within the array. I would try removing the [0] at the end of your filter.

Comment: The first time `renderCategories()` runs, it looks to me as if `filteredCategories` will be empty. The first click on an `<li>` will be the same situation.

Comment: @InchHigh Nope, they're getting the first index from the filtered array.

Comment: In any case the direct solution is simple: check to make sure that `thisCategoryObject` is not `undefined` before trying to reference a property.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy. This is ultimately what fixed it. I did try checking for undefined previously but I was doing it incorrectly. Do you want to add this as an answer? In this case only using sizeType if (thisCategoryObject != undefined) got the results I needed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your selected value does not match properly, it will give an error. When it matches properly it will work properly. Look at this example:

```
var category = [{
    name: "Women",
    parent: "Fashion",
    sizeType: "Large"
}]



var thisCategory = category.filter(value => value.name == "Women")[0];
console.log(thisCategory.sizeType); //Large
```

Answer (score 2):

According to your code, `filteredCategories` is always `[]` the first iteration of the loop, hence you receive that message. Moreover,`filteredCategories = categories.filter(value => value.parent == selectedCategory)`
 will return `[]` some other times, with you receiving the same message in the following iteration of the same loop